# How can I add a CSS Class to a Flask-Table Column

Tags: css, flask, html-table, jinja2

I want to add CSS Classes to specific Columns, the Table is made via Flask-Table. But I only found how to add Classes to the whole table is there a way to add classes to a Column too?

```
class Table(Table):
  classes = ["table", "table-hover", "clickable-row", "sortable"]
  username = Col("Username")
  vorname = Col("Vorname")
  nachname = Col("Nachname")
  gebdat = DatetimeCol("Gebdat", datetime_format="dd.MM.yyyy")
  admin = BoolCol("Rolle", yes_display='Admin', no_display='Benutzer')
  aktiv = BoolCol("Status", yes_display='aktiviert', 
  no_display='deaktiviert')
  edit = LinkCol("Bearbeiten", 'benutzerverwaltung.benutzerBearbeiten', 
  url_kwargs=dict(id='id'))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a dict in the `column_html_attrs` keyword argument when declaring a specific column inside the table class:

```py
class MyTable(Table):
    col = Col('Label', column_html_attrs = {'class': 'my-class'})
```

For more details check [this example](https://github.com/plumdog/flask_table/blob/master/examples/column_html_attrs.py) from the Flask-Table github.